# Replace jquery-templ tag

Tags: django, template-engine, jquery-templates

Is there a way to replace the main tag on jquery-tmpl ?

Example:

var data = {Name: 'Pele', Languages: ["Portuguese","English","Spanish"]};

So on a script tag we define the following template

Name: ${Name}
{{each Languages}}
 I speak $value
{{/each}}

What I wanted to change is ...
Istead of using {{each}} I'd use something like $$each$$
Instead of ${Name} I'd use something like $#Name$

You may be asking yourself why I wanna do this.

The main reason is when I because on the project we're working on uses Django and when we put code like {{each}} (even on script tag with type set to text/html) Django view engine think it's a server tag and tries to render it like if it were a server side tag.

**Update:**
What I'm looking for is a way to Set a Delimeter on jQuery-tmpl like the one that is avaiable on Mustache.js
http://mustache.github.com/mustache.5.html (look for *Set Delimiter*)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, if you want a literal `{` in your HTML, use [`templatetag`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#templatetag) with `openblock`.

```
{% templatetag openblock %}
```

If you want a literal `}`, use `closeblock`:

```
{% templatetag closeblock %}
```

So if you want `{{each}}` in your HTML, use:

```
{% templatetag openblock %}{% templatetag openblock %}each{% templatetag closeblock %}{% templatetag closeblock %}
```

Comment: Thanks Dominic. This would solve my problem but I wanted a solution based on jquery-templ like a way to Set a Delimiter like we have on mustache.js

Answer (score 1):

A different approach would be to define the template in a js file which is not processed by django as a template.

If that is not possible another alternative to Dominic's approach would be to define variables  for '{{' and '}}' maybe jqtmpl_open and jqtmpl_close accordingly and use them in template like this:

```
{{ jqtmpl_open }}each Languages{{ jqtmpl_close }}
```

This would be more readable in the template.

Changing a delimiter for jquery-tmpl is complicated. By looking at the code it seems that {{ is hard coded within some regular expressions there.

```
var oldManip = jQuery.fn.domManip, tmplItmAtt = "_tmplitem", htmlExpr = /^[^<]* (<[\w\W]+>)[^>]*$|\{\{\! /,
   newTmplItems = {}, wrappedItems = {}, appendToTmplItems, topTmplItem = { key: 0, data: {} }, itemKey = 0, cloneIndex = 0, stack = [];
```

The only solution would be to fork the jquery-tmpl for your project and change these hard coded regular expressions to accommodate your needs.

Comment: Thanks. I really didn't want to change to js because I hae a separate html file with my templates. This file is very readable and way easier to maintain than a js file with a string representing my template. What I'm looking for is a way to a delimeter on jquery-tmpl like we have on mustache.js

Answer (score 0):

This question has already been asked here [jquery template tags conflict with Django template!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021896/jquery-template-tags-conflict-with-django-template) but I thought I would add from my experience.

In a nutshell, I've added this custom "raw" template tag to my jquery-tmpl/django projects: http://www.holovaty.com/writing/django-two-phased-rendering/